# How to remove duplicate labels using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, python, labeling, arcgis-pro

I have a script that uses AddDataFromPath() to add a layer from ArcGIS Online that is regularly updated to a map in ArcGIS Pro. My script then updates and displays the labels using listLabelClasses(). Everything runs fine except for there are duplicate labels. My question is, how do I remove the duplicate labels using ArcPy? I don't see it in the ArcPy documentation so I'm wondering if there is a work around for this. Is it possible to somehow import those settings from a template layer?

Comment: Try adding a layer file with all the layer properties you want and then switching its source underneath.  Not all layer properties are exposed to ArcPy.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding but wouldn't the layer file that contains all of the layer properties that I'm switching to not have the updated fields from the new layer pulled from ArcGIS Online?

Comment: Please include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried in your question. I thought I understood what you were trying but maybe I don’t.